# Open Folder from Cell in Excel, Create Folder if it Does Not Exist

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file

I am trying to create a cell in my spreadsheet that will do a few things:

1. Open a folder based on values from two cells in a row
2. Create the folder from above two cells if it does not exist
3. Only work when I click on it for that row

Currently, I am using the Hyperlink formula to link to the folder that I manually create. I had the bright idea of linking to a batch file that opens/creates the folder from parsed data. I tried that for a good while, but have not been able to get the data from excel to the batch file.

Anyway to do this? Either in the way I described or with VBA?

My actual spread sheet has many more columns and rows, but hopefully the image below illustrates how I would like the link to the folder laid out.

[image]

Basically, I want to click "Open" in that row and it take the data from B2 and C2 and open/create a folder in C:\New Folder\B2\C2 (ex. C:\New Folder\2015\Folder 0001).

Below is the hyperlink formula I am using in Excel currently to try and accomplish this:

```
=HYPERLINK("C:\New folder\new.bat "&B2&" "&C2,"Open")
```

I get an "Cannot open the specified file" error. If I remove the cell data, it will open the program, but without the data, I have no way to create the necessary folders.

Below is the batch file I wrote to open/create the folder:

```
@echo off

set dir="C:\New folder\%1\%2"

if not exist %dir% mkdir %dir%

start "" %dir%
```

This works fine on it's own when run from the command line with the following:

```
new.bat 2015 Folder 0001
```

Any direction or help will be greatly appreciated. Thank in advance.

Comment: I guess the _space_ in `C:\New folder\new.bat` makes trouble; try the same with a folder that does not include any spaces...

Comment: Space in New folder is not an issue. I can run it as you have it typed, but not when trying to add info from the cells (i.e. new.bat 2015 folder 001). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is in your cells. But you can **build a path** from the values like this.

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim szPath as string
szPath = ws.Range("B1").Value & "\" & ws.Range("C1").Value
```

**Open a folder**
To open a folder you can use shellexecute. Declare this at the top of all you code. Above all subs and functions.

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "Shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" _
  (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
   ByVal lpOperation As String, _
   ByVal lpFile As String, _
   ByVal lpParameters As String, _
   ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
   ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
```

Then you can send it a path

```
    ShellExecute 0, "open", "C:\Temp", 0, 0, 1
    'or send it the value build from the cells
    ShellExecute 0, "open", szPath , 0, 0, 1
```

You can also open files this way

**Create files**
If you want to create files it can be done like this.

```
Dim fs As FileSystemObject
Set fs = New FileSystemObject

'Create a text file
Set ts = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\test.txt", True, False)
'or using the path from the cells
Set ts = fs.CreateTextFile(szPath & "\text.txt", True, False)
```

**Create folders**
And lastly you can create folders.

```
fs.CreateFolder ("C:\Temp\SomeNewDir")
'or using the path from the cells
fs.CreateFolder (szPath & "\SomeNewDir")
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to approach this is probably with VBA and without shell script. 
Assuming your three cells are A1, A2 and A3. You can add a button to you sheet and assign a macro like this:

```
Sub btn1_click()
Dim dir as String
Dim fso As Object
dir = Range("A1").Value & "\" & Range("A2").Value & Range("A3").Value
Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
If Not fso.folderexists(dir) Then
    fso.createfolder (dir)
End If
    Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & dir, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```